# Shift+Scroll in Firefox goes through history

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Most programs allow you to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Scroll to scroll horizontally in a window. Google Chrome does this, my editors do this, most programs do this.

Firefox is smart and uses <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Scroll to go through history, which is pretty undesirable to me. Is there a way I can make <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Scroll horizontally scroll?

Comment: It doesn't look like it. Most key commands/gestures in FF are non-configurable.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed this extension into Firefox 57 and it's working well for me:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/shift-scroll/